# Guid values are duplicated

Tags: wix, windows-installer, installation

I am creating MSI with WiX (Visual Studio Project) and hit the following problem ( I use autogenerated GUID):

```
Error   3   Component/@Id='cmpB3C5213947D323C7253292749753B540' has a @Guid value '{4617C857-DDB3-5446-ADDC-E0E2F00C8195}' that duplicates another component in this package. It is recommended to give each component its own unique GUID. C:\work2\bill\installer\Tests\TestsOutput.wxs   23510   1   Tests
```

I cant change name of this file or its path. So, I need to provide different GUID somehow for these two files.
Any idea how can I do this ? Should I put something in Product.wxs ? But what is the syntax ?

Any suggestions please.

Thanks,

Comment: Please include in the question all lines of the Wix definition file that contain the guid `{4617C857-DDB3-5446-ADDC-E0E2F00C8195}` (along with some of their context), and/or all lines containing `cmpB3C5213947D323C7253292749753B540`.

Comment: <Component Id="cmpB3C5213947D323C7253292749753B540" Directory="dir549C67B8975FF8C313FF55B8EF1AFF0A" Guid="*">
                <File Id="filDE4B25E39FBE97F2FA63F0EF570F98A5" KeyPath="yes" Source="!(wix.Product.TestsDir)\node_modules\webdriverio\lib\commands\$.js" />
            </Component>

Comment: I use heat.exe with -ag key to generate GUIDs